# Multiple Database in Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony1

What can i do for change my database conection in Symfony?

I have my database.yml with 3 different conection and I want to change "on fly" of database.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "on the fly"? Do you want to use different databases on different servers, or different connections in the same application? Based on what parameter would they switch?

Answer (score 3):

You can bind tables to a specific connection - then doctrine creates them there, and whenever you use them, doctrine automatically knows which connection to use.

This example is from [The symfony and Doctrine book, chapter 2](http://www.symfony-project.org/doctrine/1_2/en/02-Connections#chapter_02_multiple_connections):

```
Client:
  connection: master
  columns:
    name: string(255)
    username: string(255)
    password: string(255)
```